# Customizing WPF ListView control to use SurfaceScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, pixelsense

Is there a way to customize the stock WPF ListView control so that it uses a SurfaceScrollViewer (from the [Microsoft Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=801907A7-B2DD-4E63-9FF3-8A2E63932A74)) instead of a stock ScrollViewer when presenting its GridView?

I've tried looking at the [XAML files that describe the stock ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.asp) but I am new to WPF programming so I'm not sure how I could customize that XAML for my desired behaviour.

I tried using Expression Blend to retemplate the stock listbox control to use a SurfaceScrollViewer, and ended up with this template:

```
    <Style x:Key="SurfaceListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF042271"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <s:SurfaceScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This didn't produce the effect I wanted, however, as the GridView seems to hijack the scrolling behaviour and it's still row-by-row rather than the smooth panning I would have expected with the SurfaceScrollViewer. I suspect the issue might be with the following ScrollViewer template, also defined in the template:

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderStringFormat="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderStringFormat, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Columns="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="2,0,2,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0.0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0.0" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                        <DockPanel Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar}" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="false" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="White" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Width="1"/>
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="White" Height="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I'm not sure how to re-template this, as simply replacing all instances of ScrollViewer with s:SurfaceScrollViewer didn't seem to have any effect.

My backup plan is to just use a SurfaceListBox control instead of the ListView, but I already have working ListView/GridView code that I'd prefer to modify (to get the nice touch panning provided by SurfaceScrollViewer) if possible.

**UPDATE:**

After struggling with the ListView/GridView combination I eventually gave up and implemented this as a data-bound SurfaceListBox that includes a horizontal StackPanel as the SurfaceListBoxItem. So far it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use Blend to retemplate the ListView and replace it's ScrollViewer with SurfaceScrollViewer.  This would just give you scrolling capabilities though - you'd have to do more work to get all the other ListView features working with touch (selection, sorting, etc)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggestion... I tried it and posted my results as an edit to the original question. If you have any other suggestions they would be appreciated.